# Format the pretty JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, pretty-print

I'm using Node.js to pretty-print a JSON object.
This line

```
obj = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 1);
```

results in:

```
 {
  "name": "Member",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
   "Id": {
    "type": "GUID",
    "description": "Unique identifier"
   },
   "Name": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "Members name"
   }
  }
 }
```

But I want it to look this way:

```
 {
  "name": "Member",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
   "Id": {"type": "GUID", "description": "Unique identifier"},
   "Name": {"type": "string", "description": "Members name"}
  }     
 }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Not with the standard `JSON.stringify`, you either have to do it manually or google for some other guy who did it before if you are lucky (though you would have to keep track of hierarchy depth and so on to collapse newlines into spaces, so definitely not trivial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify, then use some regular expressions on the resulting string.
First strip the top level braces, then replace every newline within a {...} group with blank.

Comment: I thought of doing that. I hoped there was a simpler way of doing it :)

Comment: it's difficult since you want only the bottom level children on the same line